# Object doesn't support property or method 'assign' vuejs

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer

the site is howing blank page when i loaded it on IE 11

i added "@babel/polyfill": but no luck

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
```

............

```
bable.config.js

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app',
  ],
};
```

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'

Comment: How did you include baby polyfill?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add the following script in the head of the index.html page.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.23.0/polyfill.min.js'></script>
```